# Weird thing is happening on Live Server

Tags: php

I am facing a weird thing when i move the file to live server. Actually i have an XML file. It is read from Jquery and the contents are displayed in the HTML Page. Yesterday i made some changes in the XML file and updated in the Live server. It works perfectly in the local. But in Live server it is returning old XML file values only. I totally removed the file and moved the new file.

I thought it is referring from somewhere else. So i deleted the file and checked. But it shows  error on that time. So it refers the same file only. I opened the file in the live server itself. Everything is perfect. But it still shows old content. I don't know what is the problem happening on live server.

Can anyone help me to figure out?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I cleared many times and tried. but no use.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Can you show the js part where you read the XML. And why did you tag your question 'php'?

Comment: @smartmeta i don't think the problem is on JS. Because it was working these days whenever i made some updates. I didn't change anything in the JS file.

Comment: If it's not from browser cache, it might be from proxy cache. Can you check after changing the name of the file?

Comment: @DoSparKot if i change the file name, it is not referring any. it shows empty.

Answer (score 0):

try adding no-cache header in your php, like:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Or try accessing your xml file adding some random integer, like

```
your_xml_file.xml?id=<?php echo time(); ?>
```

Or if in js, use url like:

```
var url = "http://www.somesite.com/your_xml.xml?"+new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: The first method header is not working. Then the URL is dynamically generated and sent. So i can't change like that

Comment: @EdwinAlex you could add the last random number part to the url while dynamically generating the url... or you mean you dont have control over the url generation..?

Comment: ya. the front end work is handled by someone else. So i don't have access on those files.